# Retrival QA prompt: pronouns and possesive adjective problems

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

I am testing a simple QA Retrival chain in langchain using the ConversationalRetrievalChain and OpenAI as llm. I found it working most of the time.
The first part of the chain is based on the prompt to formulate a standalone question
which can be understood without the chat history.
the default one is:

```
"""Given the following conversation and a follow up question, rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question, in its original language.

Chat History:
{chat_history}
Follow Up Input: {question}
Standalone question:"""
```

the issue i am experimenting with this prompt is that it changes the 'my' in yours. so if if i ask what is my job it changes into what is your job.
or if I write :

human: I am Joel. nice to meet you.
if i ask in the next question: 'what is my name?'
the AI is rephrasing it 'what is your name?'

Comment: You can try to prompt engineer the LLM more precisely. Use specific instructions such as "Rephrase the follow-up question **without changing its meaning**".